# ActionMailer send email in background, queue_classic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, actionmailer, queue-classic

I am using [queue_classic](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic),
 
How can I send the following email using queue_classic?

```
Notifier.welcome(david).deliver # sends the email
```

**UPDATE**

I have added a new class method into User class

```
def.say_hello
  puts "hello!"
  Notifier.welcome(@david).deliver
end
```

`QC.enqueue("puts", "hello world")` works fine,
but `QC.enqueue("User.say_hello")` doesn't send email"
What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like queue_classic's `enqueue` method takes two arguments:

1. method to call
2. arguments to pass to this method

So you need to write a method that you can call with the two items above that will deliver your email.

```
module QueueNotifier
  def self.send_welcome_email_to_user(id)
    user = User.find(id)
    Notifier.welcome(user).deliver
  end
end
```

Then in order to enqueue these sending events, you would queue up the method name (`QueueNotifier.send_email_to_user`) and the argument (whatever the user id of `david` or the user you want to send to).

```
QC.enqueue("QueueNotifier.send_welcome_email_to_user", 14)
```

Comment: your new method isn't working because you aren't enqueueing an argument that it can use to look up the user. When the queue runs "Mailer.say_hello", it doesn't know what `@david` is.

Comment: You can see in my `enqueue` method on the last line that I am passing in the `id` for `@david` (or whatever user you want to send to). The enqueued method (`QueueNotifier.send_welcome_email_to_user`) then looks up the user when it is called, and sends it to that user. You need to pass in the id as a parameter.

Comment: @david is instance object, it has been already declared, I tried to send the email from 'class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base' class and moved the class method send_welcome_email_to_user to users class and I got it working. Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Happy to try to help. The reason I was concerned about the instance variable is that, when you queue the action you essentially lose all of the instance variables. This is because when the queue pops this job off and runs it, it is in a different session that needs its own instance variables set up.